# geom_jitter smaller increasing point size

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot some People per year as a point in my Boxplot, with the size of the point as the age. When I don't write size=Pnr$Alterpunkt (that's the column in which I have saved the size of the points based on the age. It's like 0.1 for somebody who's 15, 0.2 for somebody who's 16 and so on.) in the aes it looks perfekt, but then I don't have a legend and I would like to have one. If I write it into the aes the points become much bigger, and that doesn't look quiet good, as I have a lot of points.

Then it looks like this:

[image]

I've already tried to set the shape to "." or stroke=0. I also tried to work with the guide_legend, but nothing seems to change anything

That's the code for the plot:

```
q <- ggplot(Pnr, aes(group=year, x=year, y=Ges))
q <- q + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
q <- q + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,
                                       2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020))
q <- q + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1000,10000))
q <- q + theme(legend.position = c(0.3, 0.3),
               legend.direction = "horizontal", 
               legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA), 
               legend.title=element_blank(), 
               panel.background = element_rect(fill="white", colour="darkgrey", linetype="solid"),
               panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="lightgrey", size=0.1, linetype="solid"),
               panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="lightgrey", size=0.1, linetype="solid"),
               strip.background = element_rect(fill="lightgrey", colour = "darkgrey"))
q <- q + geom_jitter(aes(size=Pnr$Alterpunkt, shape="."), show.legend = T)
```

I'd like to have it to look like this, but with a legend

[image]

I hope somebody can help me.

Comment: On [this site](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/r-ggplot2-jitter/) it is said to use `cex` and it works. Their example simplified: `ggplot(ChickWeight, aes(x = Diet, y = weight)) + geom_jitter(cex = 0.5)`.

Comment: sadly that doesn't change anything. When I write cex into the aes the points still seem extremly thick. outsideof  the aes it would look perfekt, but then I can't include a legend..

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know how to help specifically without an example of your data. Here are some suggestions, hope something helps:

- `geom_jitter(aes(size=Alterpunkt)...` instead of `geom_jitter(aes(size=Pnr$Alterpunkt, shape=".")`, since using `$` inside ggplot calls can lead to errors, and that shape call should be outside of the `aes()`, if there at all.
- Use `scale_size_area(max_size =...)` or `scale_size_continuous(range = c(...))` to define the size of your dots. Depending on your aesthetic goals, you could apply a transformation to adjust how size varies as the underlying variable changes. In the case below, I liked the look of using `trans = scales::exp_trans(base = 1.1)` -- this made the big points significantly bigger, but not dramatically bigger, than the medium sized points. Adjust to taste.

Here's an example:
[image]

```
library(gapminder)
library(tidyverse)

fake_df <- gapminder %>%
  mutate(age = (lifeExp - 23.5)*1.7,
         Ges = (gdpPercap/1000)^0.5) %>%
  select(continent, year, age, Ges)

q <- ggplot(fake_df, aes(group=year, x=year, y=Ges))
q <- q + geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA)
q <- q + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1950, 2020, 10))
# q <- q + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1000,10000))
q <- q + theme(legend.position = c(0.3, 0.6),
               legend.direction = "horizontal", 
               legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = NA), 
               legend.title=element_blank(), 
               panel.background = element_rect(fill="white", colour="darkgrey", linetype="solid"),
               panel.grid.major = element_line(colour="lightgrey", size=0.1, linetype="solid"),
               panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="lightgrey", size=0.1, linetype="solid"),
               strip.background = element_rect(fill="lightgrey", colour = "darkgrey"))
q <- q + geom_jitter(aes(size=age), show.legend = T) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(0.01, 1.5), 
                        trans = scales::exp_trans(base = 1.2),
                        breaks = c(1, 80, 100))
q
```

Comment: thanks for your answer ! Yeah that's nearly what I had in mind. Sadly the I can't publish my data, because they are very sensitive. But in short I just have several People, their monthly income and their age per year.
Am I right, that I can only vary the size 5 times in the aes ?Because I would like to have 56 different sizes and everytime I write this into the aes I only get 5 different ones. I think thats kind of strange. It's like 15-29 has one size, than 30-39, than 40-49, 50-59 and I have the same size for People of the age from 60-70.

Comment: I don't think that's right - my understanding had been you could have as many different sizes as you want, but it will be hard to distinguish more than a few. Perhaps a simpler approach would be to use `case_when` to specify size values which look distinct enough, and map size to that variable.